# Follow up question: Differential equation math puzzle

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a follow up question to this question: [LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492187/differential-equation-math-puzzle)

The comments/answers were getting a bit crowded so I thought it would be better to open up a fresh question.

I am having trouble understanding a specific solution. In particular I don't understand how the author(s) of the solution derived the differential equation.

**Solution:**

> If a dog is located at $(r, \theta)$ in the first quadrant, then its
>   neighbor is at $(r, \theta+ \frac{\pi}{2})$
>
> $$(x_1,y_1)=(r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta)
> > \\(x_2,y_2)=(-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta)$$
>
> The slope joining these points is
>
> $$\frac{r\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}{-r\sin\theta-r\cos\theta}=\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}=\text{slope
> > of tangent line at} (r,\theta)$$
>
> $$\color{blue}{\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dr}}{\frac{dx}{dr}}=\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}=\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{\implies \frac{dr}{d\theta}=-r}$$

Can someone explain the blue part of the calculation to me. I have no idea what the author is doing. I can follow the first step (multiplying numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{dr}$)

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dr}}{\frac{dx}{dr}}=...$$

but I don't understand the steps after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has considered polar co-ordinates for this problem. 
So he has chosen $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = \tan ^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

Hence he writes $$dy=dr \sin \theta + r\cos \theta d \theta$$
$$dx=dr \cos \theta - r\sin \theta d \theta$$

That is, $$\frac{dy}{d \theta}=\frac{dr}{d \theta} \sin \theta + r\cos \theta $$ and $$\frac{dx}{d \theta}=\frac{dr}{d \theta} \cos \theta - r\sin \theta $$
Hence $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dr}{d \theta} \sin \theta + r\cos \theta}{\frac{dr}{d \theta} \cos \theta - r\sin \theta}$$

And then he computes this slope with the previously obtained slope to get the required relation.

$$\frac{\sin \theta - \cos \theta}{\sin \theta + \cos \theta}=\frac{\frac{dr}{d \theta} \sin \theta + r\cos \theta}{\frac{dr}{d \theta} \cos \theta - r\sin \theta}$$ or,
$$(\sin \theta - \cos \theta)(\frac{dr}{d \theta} \cos \theta - r\sin \theta)=(\sin \theta + \cos \theta)(\frac{dr}{d \theta} \sin \theta + r\cos \theta)$$
or, $$\frac{dr}{d \theta} = -r$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand everything except the first two lines.  As far as I can see the author (and you) started with the equations $$y=r\sin\theta \\ x=r\cos\theta$$

and ended up with $$dy=dr\sin\theta+r\cos\theta d\theta \\ dx=dr\cos\theta-r\sin\theta d\theta$$

How are you getting these equations. With respect to which variable are you differentiating?

Comment: See here $r$ and $\theta$ are both variables. So you need to take the differential of both the variables. When I am taking the differential of $r$, I keep the $\theta$ constant and when I am taking the differential of $\theta$, I keep the $r$ constant. Just like the $uv$ rule in differentiation where $u,v$ are both functions of $x$ and you differentiate both, one at a time keeping the other constant.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: It may be easier to understand if you look at the step right after that. Just take the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ w.r.t. $\theta$, using the product rule and treating $r$ as a function of $\theta$