# Differential Equation Math Puzzle 2.0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A couple of days ago I posted the following problem: [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492187/differential-equation-math-puzzle)

After solving this problem (with a lot of help from you)  I am now trying to solve it for equilaterial-triangles, -pentagons, -hexagons...(any polygon). However, I am stuck trying to derive a differential equation for the equlateral triangle-case.

Here is my (failed) attempt:

If my equilateral triangle has side length $1m$ then the radius of the circumscribed circle is $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Let $\text{Dog 1}$ be at position $r,\theta$ then $\text{Dog 2}$ will be at postion $r,\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}$

**Dog 1:**

$$x=r \cos \theta\\ y=r \sin \theta$$

**Dog 2**

$$x=r\cos (\theta+ \frac{2\pi}{3})\\y=r \sin(\theta+ \frac{2\pi}{3})$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{r \sin(\theta+ \frac{2\pi}{3})-r \sin \theta}{r\cos (\theta+ \frac{2\pi}{3})-r \cos\theta}$$

Taking differentials of $x$ and $y$

$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{dr}{d \theta}\cos \theta-r \sin \theta \\ \frac{dy}{d \theta}= \frac{dr}{d \theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{d \theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{r \sin(\theta+ \frac{2\pi}{3})-r \sin \theta}{r\cos (\theta+ \frac{2\pi}{3})-r \cos\theta}=\frac{\frac{dr}{d \theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d \theta}\cos \theta-r \sin \theta }\\ \implies (r \sin(\theta+ \frac{2\pi}{3})-r \sin \theta)(\frac{dr}{d \theta}\cos \theta-r \sin \theta)=(r\cos (\theta+ \frac{2\pi}{3})-r \cos\theta)(\frac{dr}{d \theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta)$$

Now I am stuck. The trigonometric terms don't cancel and I am left with a really messy differential equation. Did I make a mistake somewhere? Is there a way to simplify the trigonometric terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to simplify your trig terms, specifically 
$$ \cos \left( \theta + \frac{ 2 \pi}{3} \right) = - \frac{ \sqrt{3}}{2} \sin (\theta) - \frac{1}{2} \cos ( \theta) $$
$$ \sin \left( \theta + \frac{ 2 \pi}{3} \right) =  \frac{ \sqrt{3}}{2} \cos (\theta) - \frac{1}{2} \sin ( \theta) $$
Thus combing your equalities of $dy /dx$, we see
$$ \frac{ r' \sin \theta + r \cos \theta }{ r' \cos \theta - r \sin\theta} = \frac{ r \sin  ( \theta + \frac{ 2 \pi}{3} ) - r \sin\theta }{ r \cos  ( \theta + \frac{ 2 \pi}{3} ) - r \cos\theta } = \frac{ - \cos ( \theta )  + \sqrt{3} \sin\theta }{    \sin  ( \theta  ) + \sqrt{3} \cos\theta } $$
now cross multiply and simplify for $r'$,
$$ (r' \sin \theta + r \cos \theta)(  \sin  ( \theta  ) + \sqrt{3} \cos\theta) = (r ' \cos \theta - r\sin \theta )( - \cos \theta + \sqrt{3} \sin \theta ) $$
$$ \implies r' (\sin^2 \theta + \cos ^2 \theta ) = -r  (\sqrt{3} \sin^2 \theta +\sqrt{3} \cos ^2 \theta ) $$
Simplifying we see
$$ \boxed{r' = -\sqrt{3}r   } $$

Comment: Thanks! So solving the ODE: $$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-\sqrt{3}r \iff \frac{dr}{r}=-\sqrt{3}d \theta \iff r=Ce^{-\sqrt{3} \theta}$$

Is there some way I can connect this back to my original example. The solution I got for the square dog chase was $$r=Ce^{-\theta}$$

Is there some logical explanation why there is a factor of $\sqrt{3}$ in the exponent now?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I'd guess that it has to do with the inverse radius of the  circumscribed circle....

Comment: I just have one more question about my calculation. I let $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equal the slope of the line between the two dogs (thats what some other user suggested in my previous question). I still don't quite understand how that is the tangent i.e the velocity of a dog. Isn't that just the slope of the line between the positions of the two dogs. I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Think of it this way; If I want to run after a ball, I probably want to run directly towards the ball. Thus the direction I have to move is the slope of the line connecting me and the ball. Which is exactly what you calculated.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure but is it possible that you made a mistake when substituting the trig terms. Shouldnt it be: $$\frac{r'\sin \theta+r \cos \theta}{r'\cos \theta-r \sin \theta}=\frac{\sqrt{3} \cos \theta-3 \sin \theta}{-\sqrt{3} \sin \theta-3 \cos \theta}$$