# compute the acceleration of four dogs pursuit problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Four dogs pursuit problem is a classical puzzle.

> At each of the four corners of a square room (the length of a wall
> being L metres) is a dog. At a specified moment, each dog sets off at
> the same speed chasing its neighbour. At any time during the ensuing
> pursuit, each dog is always travelling directly towards the dog it is
> chasing. How far does each dog travel before they all meet?

See: https://activityworkshop.net/puzzlesgames/fourdogs/solution.html

or

https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/FourTurtles.shtml

It's not to hard to compute the original problem, by computing the speed towards the center of the square. But what if I want to compute the *acceleration* (i.e.) the change of the dog's velocity vector at any given time?

I followed [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492187/differential-equation-math-puzzle/1492600#1492600) to the original problem, but I am not sure how I can compute the acceleration out of it.

Comment: fyi, There is a demo/animation  of this problem [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/4_bugs_on_corners/index.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dogs are running at some constant speed $v =\dfrac{ds}{dt}$, where $s$ is the arclength along their path from the position at $t = 0$. For polar coordinates $$ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2$$
That is,
$$\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2+ r^2\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2$$
Or just $\dot s^2 = \dot r^2 + r^2\dot \theta^2$
Since $\frac {dr}{d\theta} = -r$, we have $\dot r = -r\dot \theta$ by the chain rule. So
$$v^2 = 2r^2\dot \theta^2$$
$v$ is positive, as is $r$, and we can assume the dogs choose to run towards the next dog in the positive $\theta$ direction, so we can take $\dot\theta$ as positive as well. So $$\frac v{\sqrt 2} = r\dot\theta$$
Differentiating with respect to $t$ again:
$$0 = \dot r\dot\theta + r\ddot\theta = -r\dot\theta^2 + r\ddot\theta$$
$$\ddot\theta = \dot\theta^2$$
which has solution $$\dot\theta = -\frac 1{t+C_1}$$ and so $$\theta =C_2 - \log(t+C_1)$$
You can now plug this into the solution of the equation $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = -r$ to get a very surprising relationship between $r$ and $t$. With these two relationships you can calculate velocity (not just speed) and acceleration.